# datagridview not showing numbers from MS Access

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, oledb

I have a datagrid view and it's datasource is MS Access(which have a datatype, currency, date/time, and numbers), It shows data in the database but doesn't show other data types, only words or any string, here is my code for adding rows

```
string[] rowData = new string[columnCount];
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < columnCount; k++)
                {
                    if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() == "System.int32")
                    {
                        rowData[k] = dr.GetInt32(k).ToString();
                    }

                    if (dr.GetFieldType(k).ToString() == "System.String")
                    {
                        rowData[k] = dr.GetString(k);
                    }
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);
            }
```

can you help me with this? thanks

Comment: What is the datatype of the fields from the Access table? Your test to look for an INT32 ignores all other potential numeric data types that the fields could be stored as.

Comment: You could try to iterate over the columns and write to the console the data type of each field as a means of determining the data types of each field.

Comment: It reads numbers but not the currency and the datetime in the database, I think I should change the data type

Comment: Post the table structure from Access if you can to your question. I wouldn't change the data type in Access, but would add additional logic to your code above to handle currency and datetime.

Comment: What if, I change the code and use databind instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the code above, I use this code, and it works

```
private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

private void loadData()
            {
                str = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
                str.Provider = "Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0";
                str.DataSource = @"\\sisc-erelim\4_Printing\VTDB\DB\VirginiTEADB2.accdb";
                con = new OleDbConnection(str.ConnectionString);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = fillTable("Select* from Accountstbl");
                dataGridView1.Columns["Password"].Visible = false;
                dataGridView1.Columns["Picture"].Visible = false;
            }

        private DataTable fillTable(string sql)
        {
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con))
            {
                da.Fill(datatable);
            }

            return datatable;
        }
```